# Access how much a device moved using accelerometer in android studio?

Tags: java, android, location, accelerometer

(I am a beginner in android, please go easy on me)

I am making an app that requires precision locating and calculating the difference between two very close locations. I highly doubt that this precision is achievable with GPS, and for now I am working with higher end phones which have good accelerometers. Basically, how do I access how much a device moved, with extreme precision?

Comment: Have you at least started to play around with getting the permission to use the accelerometers and trying to get the distances with devices? Any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this to just get the accelerometer. I have not done anything with this feature before.

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
 private SensorManager sensorManager;
 double ax,ay,az;   // these are the acceleration in x,y and z axis
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   }
   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            ax=event.values[0];
                    ay=event.values[1];
                    az=event.values[2];
            }
   }
}
```

Here is a link for a guide that seems pretty thorough and might help you down your path. [Using The Accelerometer](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125)

Answer (score 1):

It will work

```
private SensorManager sensorMan;
private Sensor accelerometer;

private float[] mGravity;
private float mAccel;
private float mAccelCurrent;
private float mAccelLast;

// In onCreate method
sensorMan = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
accelerometer = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mAccel = 0.00f;
mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

// And these:

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorMan.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorMan.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
        // Shake detection
        float x = mGravity[0];
        float y = mGravity[1];
        float z = mGravity[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
            // Make this higher or lower according to how much
            // motion you want to detect
        if(mAccel > 3){ 
        // do something
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // required method
}
```